# Python быстрый подбор сигналов для усредняющей модели

Tags: python

Есть 150 разных моделей (бинарная классификация), давших вероятности принадлежности к классу на одном датасете. Т.е есть датасет и 150 столбцов с вероятностями.

Хочу найти методом перебора 3 модели, усреднение по которым дает лучший результат.

Сейчас построение всех возможных усреднений реализовано через циклы и работает долго, задействует только одно ядро:

```
for i in range(len(good)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(good),1):
        for k in range(j+1,len(good),1):
```

`Votting Classifier` работает непосредственно с классификаторами, использовать его проблематично по ряду причин. Поэтому ищу вариант работающий с вероятностями. Возможно это делается через Votting, но я не нашла как.

Comment: GIL действует только на питоновский код, т.е. если Python выступает лишь оберткой, а ресурсоемкие операции делаются C, то сишный код будет распределен операционной системой на разные процессоры и в итоге получается прирост производительности.

Comment: добавлено https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock